# Finding mode of $f(x)$ when derivative is a constant

Tags: probability, statistics

Find the mode of the continuous random variable.

$$f(x)=2x ; \ 0\leq x\leq 1$$

What I've tried-

$$f'(x) = 2.$$

Setting this equal to $0$ gives-
$$2=0.$$

This clearly isn't true, but I don't know of another technique to find the maximum of a continuous function. Any help would be great.

The answer is $1.$

Answer (score 1):

It is a strictly increasing function over $[0,1]$ because $f'(x)=2>0$. So, $f(x) < f(y), \ \forall \ x <y$.
$$\implies f(x) \leq f(1), \ \forall x \leq 1.$$
$$\implies \max_{x \in [0,1]} f(x) = f(1).$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $2x$ has its maximum on the *boundary* of the interval, which is why the derivative can fail to be zero.  Your method is good for looking for maxima within the interval.

Checking all points where $f' = 0$ (there are none) as well as the boundary points, $x = 0$ and $x=1$, we find that the highest value of $f$ is $f(1) = 2$, so the mode is $x = 1$.

Drawing a picture for each problem will help.